# Is storing authorization tokens on Android 's AccountManager secure?

Tags: android

How secure it is (not) to store a JWT token (for instance) in Android's AccountManager?

I know a good alternative would be to use the android KeyStore, specially with the new Jetpack Security libs, but I'd like some folks input about the risks of doing the other way.

Ref: Android [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager)

Comment: This question has an answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160882/android-where-are-stored-the-data-put-into-accountmanager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer from the security standpoint, and according to the [linked answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44162509), the real risk is that a root user can actually exfiltrate the JWT.

Android is hardened enough to that processes do not interfere each other. But if the user running the device has root capabilities, and given that your application can't detect root for sure, there is the possibility that any app running as root, voluntarily by the device owner, or maliciously, can exfitrate the token

> This database can be found at /data/system/users/0/accounts.db, where 0 is user's ID.

And is not encrypted.

Comment: I've read it somewhere that it's base64 encoded since 2.3. That's a long time ago. I'd say that if a root user could read it then it's not different than storing the token in internal private data. Do you know if something else has changed on that matter?

Comment: No, but I doubt. You could still use hardware storage on modern devices, but I still object that `root` might do something. You should also review your security design, because everything stored in a device under the user's control is **accessible to the user**. If you don't want that, you need to take completely different approaches

Comment: I mean, there is generally no harm if the user who owns a device (and an account) is capable of seeing a JWT. Happens every time with browser's developer tools, and nobody complained ever.